# Sticky bar glitch on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a sticky scroll bar but when I scroll down it shows some glitch and put the scroll bar back to top again (Resolution 1920x1080). It works fine on smaller resolution.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Cache selectors for faster performance.
    var $window = $(window),
        $mainMenuBar = $('#mainMenuBar'),
        $mainMenuBarAnchor = $('#mainMenuBarAnchor');

    // Run this on scroll events.
    $window.scroll(function() {
        var window_top = $window.scrollTop();
        var div_top = $mainMenuBarAnchor.offset().top;
        if (window_top > div_top) {
            // Make the div sticky.
            $mainMenuBar.addClass('stick');
            $mainMenuBarAnchor.height($mainMenuBar.height());
        }
        else {
            // Unstick the div.
            $mainMenuBar.removeClass('stick');
            $mainMenuBarAnchor.height(0);
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
    <div id="top" style="width: 100%; height: 100px; background: #ccc; margin: 0;">Top Panel</div>

<div id="mainMenuBarAnchor"></div>
<div id="mainMenuBar" style="width: 100%; height: 50px; background: #999; margin: 0;">Sticky Panel</div>

<div id="content" style="width: 100%; height: 630px; background: #ccc; margin: 0;">
    Content Panel
    <br/>
    <br/>
    This panel will not jump when the sticky panel becomes stuck.
</div>
```

CSS

```
.stick {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

Here is the snap of the scroll bar which I cannot scroll down using mouse roller. The scroll bar needs to be dragged down explicitly
http://i67.tinypic.com/16i7c5y.png

Here is a fiddle for you to see https://jsfiddle.net/mnaveed76/jsm3quk9/9/

**Update**: 
The problem occurs in Firefox browser only.

Comment: on 1920×1080 it does not scroll at all, since your example is shorter in height.. Post an example that actually exhibits the problem. (*i have not been able to reproduce it even if making the `#content` div larger*)

Comment: There is a text at the bottom of the #content div. When I scroll down using mouse roller it goes back again to original position.